# PHP/MYSQL How do you store a multidimensional array in a database - json or another table?

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, multidimensional-array

I am currently developing an application which requires the storage of a multidimensional array in a database. Currently I am taking the array which is 3 tiers deep and could be any size as it is populated with user-generated information, and using `json_encode()` to convert it into a `string` and enter it into the database.
The issue with this is that the single field is extremely large and difficult to read, to update the data I have to retrieve the data, decode it, update it, encode it and re-upload it. If the site did become used by many I am unaware of how this would scale.
I think the main alternative would be to create another table, with each row accessed by a unique `id` stored in the main table, but again I am unsure how well this would scale
Which is better? Any help much appreciated:)

Comment: If the string requires no interrogation/analysis/comparison with other strings, then carry on as you are. Otherwise, see normalisation

Comment: Concerning MySQL, don't think in arrays or dimensions. Think in relations!

Comment: `the main alternative would be to create another table, with each row accessed by a unique id stored in the main table` That's effectively how the db will be storing your json TEXT/BLOB anyway - the table only has a pointer to where the value is actually stored. Of the two choices, let the db do it. You don't say what the data is, or how you're using it, you could consider storing the data elsewhere (even, in a file). Note that the lack of details in the question is reflected by the vague nature of the answers you've received.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure how many tiers deep your array could be it's really hard to design the db schema.So best way to store is in a text field which you are doing already.

As for as scaling is concerned with proper indexing and partitioning you and scale you application however one field with large text value has nothing to do with scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Creating multiple database tables and relationships between these tables to group your data together will probably be easier to maintain and will give you the ability to query/filter results based on columns rather than having to retrieve your data, decode it and iterate over it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are not sure about how deep your array can be ,,,,than either you build a well constructed database that will be bit difficult so just do as you have planned. As I would suggest make use of **functions** as much as you can.

*Function for encoding* and *function for decoding* for json data (of any tiers) and use these functions and carry out your updates.

Using separate functions will obviously beautify your project and codes wont mess up.